# Filter for author exact match regardless of case

Tags: python

I have a linked list for a catalog and book. I am trying to filter by author and return with the books that are of exact match, however, it says that my book type has no such attribute whenever i run it. I also try to upper case the author names so that it is consistent and match will return even if input are of different case

```
class Book:
    def __init__(self, title, author, year):
        if not isinstance(title, str):
            raise Exception("title must be a string")
        if not isinstance(author, str):
            raise Exception("author must be a string")
        if not isinstance(year, int):
            raise Exception("year must be an integer")

        self.title = title
        self.author = author
        self.year = year

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if isinstance(other, Book):
            return self.title == other.title and \
                self.author == other.author and \
                 self.year == other.year
        return NotImplemented

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"{repr(self.title)} by {repr(self.author)} {self.year})"


class Catalog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []

    def filter_by_author(self, author):
        xs = self.lst.copy()
        xs = [author.capitalize() for author in xs]
        if author.upper() in xs:
            return self.lst

# driver

b1 = Book("1984", "George Orwell", 1949)
b2 = Book("Brave new world", "Aldous Huxley", 1932)
b3 = Book("El aleph", "Jorge Louis Borges", 1949)
b4 = Book("The devils of Loudun", "Aldous Huxley", 1952)

cat = Catalog()

cat.add(b1)
cat.add(b2)
cat.add(b3)
cat.add(b4)


la = cat.filter_by_author("aldous huxley")
assert la == [b2, b4]
```

I am trying to assert if author matches the books in the catalog, the list will return with the books

Comment: What error appears and where did you define `capitalize()`?

Comment: When asking in SO, if you get an error, post the full message

Comment: where is the add() method of Catalog defined?  you're checking if the author exists in any book then returning the full catalog list.  you're creating a lot of unnecessary lists, i.e. you copy self.lst but then you immediately overwrite XS with a new list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to make a copy of your lst, since your generator below makes a new list anyway. I also don't understand why you are using `.capitalize()`

The problem is that in your `list comprehension` you go through each `book`, call the current `Book` `"author"` and then try to captialize `author`. `author` however is a `Book`, which you cannot capitalize. In your code you'd need to call `author.author.capitalize()`, or you just use the following:

```py
def filter_by_author(self, author):
  author = author.lower()
  return [book for book in self.lst if book.author.lower() == author]
```

*Edit to respond to comment*

In python you can easily check whether a string contains a certain substring:

```py
def filter_by_author(self, author):
  author = author.lower()
  return [book for book in self.lst if author in book.author.lower()]
```

I am not sure however that is what you want, because `"John" in "Johnathan"` is True. So you'd probably want to check if any of the names are `"John"`

```py
def filter_by_author(self, author):
  author = author.lower()
  return [book for book in self.lst if author in book.author.lower().split()]
```

This first splits the string at a certain string. Eg. `"John Nathan Last-name".split(" ") == ["John", "Nathan", "Last-name"]`
The arguments default value is `" "`, so you don't need to pass it in.

Comment: Thanks! can i ask how can this be altered if I do not need an exact match? say for instance i filter by John, but the return should contain every author with John as part of its name

Comment: @user20250841 I have updated my answer accordingly. Next time I suggest that you understand the given code, and just google the change you want to make yourself, in this case that could be: "check if string contains string python"

Answer (score 0):

add() was not defined.

str.capitalize() is different from str.upper()

do not return self.lst itself

```py
class Catalog:
    def __init__(self):
        self.lst = []

    def add(self, b):
        self.lst.append(b)

    def filter_by_author(self, author):
        return [b for b in self.lst if b.author.upper() == author.upper()]
```